# Only one outgoing link every 30 seconds

Tags: php

I'm working on a website now with a lot of external links. All links are going through a PHP file called: out.php

So a normal external link would be something like: out.php?url=http://www.google.com

My question is how to prevent people from clicking multiple links at a time? I want them to click only one link in 30 seconds for example. If they click another link an error should be appear telling them to wait the rest for the seconds, before they can visit another page.

Using cookies is not an option, because they still can disable the cookies.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do the users of this site have to login before clicking the links?

Comment: i edited my answer to help u out there

Comment: @Tim Cooper: Not necessarily. 

@Neal: Thanks for your answer, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the url which was clicked somewhere (file, database, ...) and the timestamp when it was clicked last time. Then for every click check the timestamp of the given url (if exists). If it is inside the 30 seconds windows ignore the request, otherwise use the request and update the timestamp field. If you need to separate it for each user as well save the IP (or userid if you have), too.

Comment: Requiring a login would work, IP address would not, as described in my comment to Neal's answer

Comment: @Gareth:
I'm aware of that. Users get points for visiting websites, that's why I want them to click only the websites they are interested in. And you get only points if you're logged in. So not logged in users, may click as many as they want. 

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: I choose this one as the best answer. Thanks Neal for your help anyway! It's appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can say that you need cookies in order to view the site
   You can use session cookies:
   if they view page A:

```
   if(!isset($_SESSION['A']))
       $_SESSION['A'] = time();
   else {
       if((time() - $_SESSION['A']) <= 30000){
            $_SESSION['A'] = time();
            die('YOU JUST WERE HERE 30 SECONDS AGO! TRY AGAIN LATER!');
       }
   }
   $_SESSION['A'] = time();
```

Or something like that, the above code is not perfected

Comment: This got downvoted probably because of the tone, but it's pretty accurate. You can't reply on IP address to uniquely identify a user, as an IP address could cover a whole company, or a whole class of 3G internet users. Any other identifying information can be spoofed or cleared. It all depends on how much you really care that the system can be gamed

Comment: @Gareth, changed the tone a bit ^_^

Comment: still not sure why this is still voted down.. it is a 'correct' answer

Comment: I didn't voted it down. I voted it up. :)
Both solutions are great, so I'm still in doubt which one I should use.